# Duplicate .get() functionality with a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert some code from dictionaries to dataframes. How do I duplicate the functionality of a dictionary's .get()? What I have mostly works, but I can't figure out how to get the default value working. For example, in the below code, the output of the dataframe should include an index1 value for 234. (For various reasons, I cannot change the format of the incoming data.)

```
import pandas


def build_dataframe(data2):
    tuple_list = []
    data_dict = {}
    for source in sorted(data2.keys()):
        tuple_list.extend([(source, target) for target in sorted(data2[source])])
        data_dict.update({(source, target): data2[source][target] for target in sorted(data2[source])})
    multi_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple_list, names=["index1", "index2"])
    df = pandas.DataFrame(index=multi_index, columns=[0], data={0: data_dict})
    return df


def dataframe_get(df, index2, default_value=0):
    return  df.loc(axis=0)[:, index2]


def dict_get(input_dict, key, default_value=0):
    return {index1: dictionary.get(key, default_value) for index1, dictionary in input_dict.iteritems()}


data = {123: {6544: 44, 23423: 66, 12: 65}, 234: {725: 42, 7245: 62}}
df_data = build_dataframe(data)
print df_data
print dict_get(data, 12, 999)
print dataframe_get(df_data, 12, 999)
```

Result:

```
                0
index1 index2    
123    12      65
       6544    44
       23423   66
234    725     42
       7245    62

{234: 999, 123: 65}

                0
index1 index2    
123    12      65
```

EDIT: I got something:

```
def dataframe_get(df, index2, default_value=0):
    levels = df.index.levels[:-1] + [[index2]]
    new_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(levels, names=["index1", "index2"])
    data = df.reindex(new_index)
    return data.loc(axis=0)[:, index2].fillna(default_value)
```

This is almost correct, but I need to drop the index2; I'm still working on this.

```
index1 index2       
123    12       65.0
234    12      999.0
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, got this working:

```
def dataframe_get(df, index2, default_value=0):
    index_length = len(df.index.levels)
    levels = df.index.levels[:-1] + [[index2]]
    new_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(levels, names=["index1", "index2"])
    data = df.reindex(new_index)
    data.index = data.index.droplevel(index_length - 1)
    return data.fillna(default_value)
```